# image upload and preview in mvc 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i am learing mvc 2 by converting a asp.net website.in my page i have to upload a image and show the preview of image.

screen shoot of my asp.net page is given below.

[image: Screen shoot of my asp.net]

i have created the model as

```
public class Contest
    {
        public int contestid { get; set; }
        public string ContestName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public string contestimage { get; set; }
    }
```

in my controller

```
public ActionResult Createcontest()
{
   ContestModel contest = new ContestModel();
   return View(contest);
}
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Createcontest(ContestModel contest)
    {
///inserting data
      return View(contest);
    }
```

if i am using iframe in my view to upload image.then how can i bind the file name to contestimage.(i am saving contestimage to database).
is there any other method to upload image.

Comment: you might want to learn mvc3, cuz it's the latest version atm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//in controller u can do this

```
public ActionResult Show( int id )
     {


        byte[] Filecontent1 = null;


        foreach (byte[] Filecontent in db.ExecuteStoreQuery<byte[]>
       ("select Filecontent from [barcodes] where Barcode_Id = @p0 ", id))
        {
            Filecontent1 = Filecontent;
        }

        var imageData =   Filecontent1;

        return File( imageData, "image/jpg" );
    }
```

//put this in view for diplaying
//automatically hooks the Actionresult show

```
<tr><img src='<%= Url.Action("Show", "contollername",new {id = Model.itemid }) %>' /></tr>
```

id it takes from url:http://localhost//page/1

where 1 is the itemid

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use  `<img src= ...>` to preview image

Here is an example :- http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2010/04/03/image-preview-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Upload image to database and preview it: 
http://byatool.com/mvc/asp-net-mvc-upload-image-to-database-and-show-image-dynamically-using-a-view/